# Multiple spaces and dots between letters

Tags: bash, sed, filter

Currently I am writing a script to read some logs for me and I started to add some filters to it, on of them being a filter to find swear words and I gat stuck.

So this part is working:

```
SWEARS=$(echo "g *t *f *o" | sed 's/ /[[:space:]]/g')
cat $LOGFILE | egrep --color='always' -iw $SWEARS
```

Here it will find where people will sat 'gtfo' no matter how much spaces they put in between the letters. Please ignore that I have to write ' *' in between every letter for now.

Now if people write g.t.f.o it will not find anything.
What i came up with was

```
SWEARS=$(echo "g *t *f *o" | sed 's/ /[[[:space:]]|\\.]/g')
```

But that does not seem to work. Could someone help me out here and explain to me why its not working?

EDIT:
Lets assume that the logfile has alot of lines and one of them being: "I hate you g.t..f o"
I would like it to find the 'g.t..f o'

So the output would be:
I hate you **g.t..f o**
(The bold being colored)

It should not return any other lines.

Comment: `echo "g *t *f *o"` returns `g *t *f *o` only.

Comment: @Avinash Raj As i see your reputation, you clearly have more knowledge than me. As i see what happens is I pipe my echo string to the sed and replace the white space by [[[:space:]]|\.] according to my output. 

So where do I go wrong with my thought?

Comment: this `[[[:space:]]|\\.]` in the replacement part, replaces spaces with exactly `[[[:space:]]|\\.]` , Give us an example with expected output.

Comment: want to replace multiple spaces or dots with what?

Comment: I edit the post with what I expect the output to be.

Comment: In this case I could yes, but a line might only contain the gtfo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, you have this:

```
$ echo "g *t *f *o" | sed 's/ /[[:space:]]/g'
g[[:space:]]*t[[:space:]]*f[[:space:]]*o
```

This matches `g t f o` with any number of spaces between the letters.   To match any number of spaces or periods between the letters:

```
$ echo "g *t *f *o" | sed 's/ /[[:space:].]/g'
g[[:space:].]*t[[:space:].]*f[[:space:].]*o
```

To apply this to your sample input:

```
$ SWEARS=$(echo "g *t *f *o" | sed 's/ /[[:space:].]/g')
$ echo "I hate you g.t..f o" | egrep --color='always' -iw $SWEARS
I hate you g.t..f o
```

Or,

```
$ echo "I hate you g....t  ..f . o" | egrep --color='always' -iw $SWEARS
I hate you g....t  ..f . o
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to get like this,

```
$ echo "I hate you g.t..f o" | grep -E '\b[A-Za-z]([ .]+[A-Za-z]\b)+'
I hate you g.t..f o
```

This would display `g.t..f o` in red color.